# Jetty maxes out number of Connectors

Tags: java, http, jetty

We start the Jetty Server in Java and have a pretty straight forward process for that: API gets called, server starts. There will be no magic happening while starting Jetty, its a static process that shouldn't depend on anyhting. However we experience issues with some startups, where Jetty will try to open (presumably endlessly many) Connectors and maxes out the ThreadPool's size. OK-Runs will have exactly one Server Connector, as I would expect with a 4-core CPU and no Server Connector count set.
We also tried to navigate around the problem by setting the number of Server Connectors (to one), still Jetty would ramp up the count and fail to start, because there would be not enough threads available.
Even more curious, another API-User (different application) never had this issue once. This has all been tested on the same machine, same OS, often the same day even.
We use Jetty 9.4.38. This is what the Exception says:

could not subscribe connector
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Insufficient configured threads: required=200 < max=200 for QueuedThreadPool[qtp370296980]@16124894{STARTED,8<=144<=200,i=0,r=-1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@3825f21{s=0/6,p=0}]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ThreadPoolBudget.check(ThreadPoolBudget.java:165)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ThreadPoolBudget.leaseTo(ThreadPoolBudget.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ThreadPoolBudget.leaseFrom(ThreadPoolBudget.java:191)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:320)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:81)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:234)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)

Comment: How are you starting Jetty?

Comment: "We also tried to navigate around the problem by setting the number of Server Connectors (to one)" ??  Can you explain this a bit more, how did you do that? (there's no such setting in Jetty)

Comment: start() is called on an Instance of org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server

Comment: My understanding of Jetty's implementation was, it will take care of Connector unless you set a connector for the Server explicitly. That is what I did, I created a ServerConnector with exactly 1 acceptor and selector and assigned this Connector to the server.

Comment: Jetty has only 1 self created connector scenario, the `new Server(int port)` constructor, there's no other mechanism for Jetty itself to create a connector.  If you have 200 connectors, then your code specifically added 200 connectors.

Comment: Edit your question and include the INFO logging output from `org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ThreadPoolBudget` (it should explain what the budget / leases are specifically for)

Comment: Well I suspected but thanks for confirming, will need to find where this happens then.

Answer (score 0):

The `ThreadPoolBudget` being reported is indicating that you have some combination of technologies and/or components that are requiring a thread load of 200 threads, but your max threads is exactly 200.

The output from INFO logging of the named logger `org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ThreadPoolBudget` will report the lease / budget of the various components you have.

Output will have a format indicating ...

```
INFO: <component> requires <num> threads from <thread-pool>
```

That will tell you what components are requesting that amount of threads.

The `<component>` will include the hashcode / object identity of the component, if you see the same one repeated (eg: `Foo@1234` and `Foo@789` would be different object instances, but `Bar@575` and `Bar@575` would be the same object instance), then you have a bad initialization of your Server. (likely not using the `LifeCycle` properly)